# List of indexes into array; find indexes where array[index] is duplicated

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an array (let's call it `indexArray`) of indexes into another array (called `sequence`). I want to scan the original array, `sequence`, to see if the values at these indexes are duplicates. For example, if there is a value equal to `sequence[indexarray[(value at index 1)]]` in `sequence`, then I want to delete the index value from `indexArray`. At the end, I will have an array with only the indexes whose values are not repeated.

Answer (score 5):

One way to approach it would be this:

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:sequence];
for (NSNumber *index in indexarray) {
    id object = [sequence objectAtIndex:[index integerValue]];
    NSUInteger objectCount = [countedSet countForObject:object];
    if (objectCount > 1) {
        NSLog("%@ is duplicate", object);
    }
}
```

**Performance:** Compared to checking each object for duplicates manually, which has an operation time of about `O(n*m)`, (with `n`, `m` being the arrays' sizes.) the use of an [NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) brings it down to an operation time of about `O(n+m)`.